# How to "shift" objects from ActiveRecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method

```
def gen_events(score)
  events = location.events
  (1..rand(5..7)).each do |n|
    random = rand(0.139..1).round(3)
    rarity = Character.get_rarity(random)
    event = events.where(rarity: rarity).shuffle.shift #<-- HERE
    self.events << event    
  end
end
```

Currently, the `shift` method only grabs the first element, but doesn't remove it, how can I go about making it so that it does both?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an array: `events.where(rarity: rarity)`, this is an ActiveRecord scope, you can't remove things from it without destroying and erasing them from database. Instead, you should keep an array of object you already found, and use it to filter future results:

```
def gen_events(score)
    events = location.events
    new_events = []
    (1..rand(5..7)).each do |n|
        random = rand(0.139..1).round(3)
        rarity = Character.get_rarity(random)
        event = events.where(rarity: rarity).where.not(id: new_events.map(&:id).sample
        new_events << event
    end
    self.events << new_events    
end
```

Comment: what does the sample method and the & operator do?

Comment: `sample` returns random element from an array (it is delegated to AR association target), notation `map(:&:method)` is a shortcut for `map {|event| event.method}`

Comment: Hmm the method doesnt seem to work, i receive "undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Event:0x00000005b1f788>", even though the event has an ID attribute
"